# Undefined property error with Rumbelow's My_Model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-3

I just added Rumbelow's My_Model to CodeIgniter 3.1.9 and created a new empty model like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends MY_Model {



}
```

And loaded the model in my Login controller:

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
```

And this error occures:
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Login::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 73
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: E:\Projects\My Project\application\core\MY_Model.php Line: 108
>   Function: __get
>
> File: E:\Projects\My Project\application\controllers\Login.php Line: 9
>   Function: model
>
> File: E:\Projects\My Project\index.php Line: 316 Function:
>   require_once

I looked for Line: 108 in My_Model.php. It's like this:

```
$this->_database = $this->db;
```

What's the problem?
Is something broken with CodeIgniter 3.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to load database library.
I added it to autoload.php and it works now.

Comment: You can load database in Model's constructor also $this->load->database();